# Should this audio file have ogg or opus as file name extension?

Tags: audio, encoding, file-formats

```
bash $ mediainfo myaudio.opus
General
Complete name                            : /Users/qaz/myaudio.opus
Format                                   : Ogg
File size                                : 3.52 MiB
Duration                                 : 3 min 48 s
Overall bit rate                         : 129 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf60.3.100

Audio
ID                                       : 4122949963 (0xF5BF394B)
Format                                   : Opus
Duration                                 : 3 min 48 s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Writing library                          : Lavf60.3.100
Language                                 : English
```

Should I keep it as `myaudio.opus` or is it better to rename it as `myaudio.ogg`?

Answer (score 2):

Ogg is a container format, and Opus files use the Ogg container.  `.opus` is therefore correct.  Historically, the extension used for Ogg/Vorbis files was `.ogg` (by now `.ogv` is available but not always in use) and there is no guarantee that a file declared to process `.ogg` files is actually able to deal with the Opus codec inside.

So I would not rename.